# Create tabs inside Plugins Admin Page

Tags: plugins, admin

I am developing my own plugin and I am trying to figure out how to add tabs to my admin page.

Is the process similar to how we add meta boxes?

Ie, something like add_tab_box(...); and I specify a callback?

When I say tabs I mean tabs like below:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I advice you to read this topic: [Here you can find complete guide making options page with tabbed content.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-5-tabbed-navigation-for-your-settings-page--wp-24971)

Or you can just copy the html of the tabbed page that you've liked, and use it on your own options page.

I made my options page with tabs too, but with api. Tabs and the fields are taken from config array.

[Here](https://github.com/anvarulugov/AUS-basic/blob/master/framework/defaults.php) you can see `$aus_tabs` array.

And [here](https://github.com/anvarulugov/AUS-basic/blob/master/framework/classes/class-options.php) is the class of options page.

[This class](https://github.com/anvarulugov/AUS-basic/blob/master/framework/classes/class-input.php) is used to render the form fields.

Comment: Your last two suggested urls are not working